# Java SwingX Setup and use of JXCollapsiblePanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, swingx

I am trying to create a panel which opens to the left of the rest of my GUI. I am working in Eclipse. I added `swingx-core-1.6.2.jar` to my build path. I can import  `org.jdesktop.swingx.JXCollapsiblePane` and then make a new `JXCollapsiblePane`, but in order to set the orientation of the pane, I need to do something like:

```
JXCollapsiblePane myCollapsingPane = new JXCollapsiblePane();
mycollapsingPane.setOrientation(JXCollapsiblePane.Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
```

However, this fails saying that Orientation cannot be resolved. So, I tried importing 
`org.jdesktop.swingx.JXCollapsiblePane.Orientation`, which also fails saying that it cannot be resolved.
I'm probably missing something silly here; how do I set the panel to open to the side rather than vertically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JXCollapsiblePanel` at 1.6.2 has no `setOrientation` method. Also, there is `JXCollapsiblePane.Orientation` enum any more. It was probably dropped.

However, there is `JXCollapsiblePane.Direction` and there `JXCollapsiblePanel.setDirection()`, it is probably a replacement.

Here is a [thread](http://www.java.net/node/676517) about this.